# How to set AVPlayerItem to nil when observer does not complete

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I add a **observer** named '**status**' into **AVPlayerItem**.
Send the observer then set  AVPlayerItem to nil when the observer does not complete

I have remove the observer when dealloc AVPlayerItem

Get the following error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7dc5e7d0 of
>   class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were
>   still registered with it. Current observation info:
>    (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b8ad140>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused initial the  avplayeritem by async

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the `AVPlayerItem` should be observing anything, it's hard to say in your case without a concrete example. Generally the flow for this would be that your **controller** be an observer on some *notification* from the `AVPlayerItem`.

For example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then when you're done (i.e. when you are setting the AVPlayerItem to `nil`), you remove the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
```

If you provide more detail, maybe I can help more. Thanks!

**Edit:**

In swift it would be...

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "movieDidReachEnd", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: I want to observer 'ReadyToPlay' status  ,notification seem not support

Comment: I am facing same issue in AVPlayerItem.

Answer (score 0):

Before you set the playerItem to nil, remove the observer:

```
playerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
```

If you wait until deinit/dealloc, after you've already set the playerItem to nil, then you won't have a reference to it anymore to remove the observers.

Comment: I have removed the observer before dealloc the AVPlayerItem, but I get the error caused by  AVPlayerItem is dealloc

Comment: Can you post the code where you remove the observers?